# Debian 10 dpkg/apt downgrade errors

Tags: linux, debian, apt, dpkg, amd-graphics

Linux noob here:

I was trying to install a newer version of AMD Mesa to help with games and video editing. It appears that the Buster repository only has versions 18.x. I tried using the package from the Sid repository but kept downgrading when using apt -f install. I downloaded all the .deb files required for Mesa 20 from debian.org and installed them using dpkg -i (this was a bad idea, per DontBreakDebian). I am trying to downgrade any packages that I installed manually, back to the versions used by Buster.

Using Inkscape as an example (already installed):

```
root@CBTS-WBPC5:/home/cbts/Downloads# apt install inkscape
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
inkscape is already the newest version (0.92.4-3).
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 i965-va-driver:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libavutil56:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libbsd0 : Breaks: libbsd0:i386 (!= 0.11.3-1) but 0.9.1-2+deb10u1 is to be installed
 libbsd0:i386 : Breaks: libbsd0 (!= 0.9.1-2+deb10u1) but 0.11.3-1 is to be installed
 libdrm-intel1:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.38) but it is not going to be installed
 libdw1 : Depends: libelf1 (= 0.176-1.1) but 0.183-3 is to be installed
 libedit2 : Breaks: libedit2:i386 (!= 3.1-20191231-2+b1) but 3.1-20181209-1 is to be installed
 libedit2:i386 : Breaks: libedit2 (!= 3.1-20181209-1) but 3.1-20191231-2+b1 is to be installed
 libelf-dev : Depends: libelf1 (= 0.176-1.1) but 0.183-3 is to be installed
 libelf1 : Breaks: libelf1:i386 (!= 0.183-3) but 0.176-1.1 is to be installed
 libelf1:i386 : Breaks: libelf1 (!= 0.176-1.1) but 0.183-3 is to be installed
 libexpat1 : Breaks: libexpat1:i386 (!= 2.2.10-2) but 2.2.6-2+deb10u1 is to be installed
 libexpat1:i386 : Breaks: libexpat1 (!= 2.2.6-2+deb10u1) but 2.2.10-2 is to be installed
 libexpat1-dev : Depends: libexpat1 (= 2.2.6-2+deb10u1) but 2.2.10-2 is to be installed
 libncurses-dev : Depends: libtinfo6 (= 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2) but 6.2+20201114-2 is to be installed
                  Depends: libncurses6 (= 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2) but 6.2+20201114-2 is to be installed
 libncurses6 : Breaks: libncurses6:i386 (!= 6.2+20201114-2) but 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 is to be installed
 libncurses6:i386 : Breaks: libncurses6 (!= 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2) but 6.2+20201114-2 is to be installed
 libncursesw6 : Depends: libtinfo6 (= 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2) but 6.2+20201114-2 is to be installed
 libstdc++6 : Breaks: libstdc++6:i386 (!= 10.2.1-6) but 8.3.0-6 is to be installed
 libstdc++6:i386 : Breaks: libstdc++6 (!= 8.3.0-6) but 10.2.1-6 is to be installed
 libtinfo-dev : Depends: libtinfo6 (= 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2) but 6.2+20201114-2 is to be installed
 libtinfo6 : Breaks: libtinfo6:i386 (!= 6.2+20201114-2) but 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2 is to be installed
 libtinfo6:i386 : Breaks: libtinfo6 (!= 6.1+20181013-2+deb10u2) but 6.2+20201114-2 is to be installed
 libva-drm2:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.4.16) but it is not going to be installed
 libva-x11-2:i386 : Depends: libdrm2:i386 (>= 2.3.1) but it is not going to be installed
 libvulkan-dev : Depends: libvulkan1 (= 1.1.97-2) but 1.2.162.0-1 is to be installed
 libvulkan1 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.29) but 2.28-10 is to be installed
              Breaks: libvulkan1:i386 (!= 1.2.162.0-1) but 1.1.97-2 is to be installed
 libvulkan1:i386 : Breaks: libvulkan1 (!= 1.1.97-2) but 1.2.162.0-1 is to be installed
 libwayland-client0 : Breaks: libwayland-client0:i386 (!= 1.19.0-2) but 1.16.0-1 is to be installed
 libwayland-client0:i386 : Breaks: libwayland-client0 (!= 1.16.0-1) but 1.19.0-2 is to be installed
 libwayland-dev : Depends: libwayland-client0 (= 1.16.0-1) but 1.19.0-2 is to be installed
 libx11-6 : Breaks: libx11-6:i386 (!= 2:1.7.0-2) but 2:1.6.7-1+deb10u1 is to be installed
 libx11-6:i386 : Breaks: libx11-6 (!= 2:1.6.7-1+deb10u1) but 2:1.7.0-2 is to be installed
 libx11-dev : Depends: libx11-6 (= 2:1.6.7-1+deb10u1) but 2:1.7.0-2 is to be installed
 libx11-xcb-dev : Depends: libx11-xcb1 (= 2:1.6.7-1+deb10u1) but 2:1.7.0-2 is to be installed
 libx11-xcb1 : Breaks: libx11-xcb1:i386 (!= 2:1.7.0-2) but 2:1.6.7-1+deb10u1 is to be installed
 libx11-xcb1:i386 : Breaks: libx11-xcb1 (!= 2:1.6.7-1+deb10u1) but 2:1.7.0-2 is to be installed
 libxau-dev : Depends: libxau6 (= 1:1.0.8-1+b2) but 1:1.0.9-1 is to be installed
 libxau6 : Breaks: libxau6:i386 (!= 1:1.0.9-1) but 1:1.0.8-1+b2 is to be installed
 libxau6:i386 : Breaks: libxau6 (!= 1:1.0.8-1+b2) but 1:1.0.9-1 is to be installed
 libxcb-dri3-0 : Breaks: libxcb-dri3-0:i386 (!= 1.14-3) but 1.13.1-2 is to be installed
 libxcb-dri3-0:i386 : Breaks: libxcb-dri3-0 (!= 1.13.1-2) but 1.14-3 is to be installed
 libxcb-dri3-dev : Depends: libxcb-dri3-0 (= 1.13.1-2) but 1.14-3 is to be installed
 libxcb-present-dev : Depends: libxcb-present0 (= 1.13.1-2) but 1.14-3 is to be installed
 libxcb-present0 : Breaks: libxcb-present0:i386 (!= 1.14-3) but 1.13.1-2 is to be installed
 libxcb-present0:i386 : Breaks: libxcb-present0 (!= 1.13.1-2) but 1.14-3 is to be installed
 libxcb-randr0-dev : Depends: libxcb-randr0 (= 1.13.1-2) but 1.14-3 is to be installed
 libxcb-sync-dev : Depends: libxcb-sync1 (= 1.13.1-2) but 1.14-3 is to be installed
 libxcb-sync1 : Breaks: libxcb-sync1:i386 (!= 1.14-3) but 1.13.1-2 is to be installed
 libxcb-sync1:i386 : Breaks: libxcb-sync1 (!= 1.13.1-2) but 1.14-3 is to be installed
 libzstd1 : Breaks: libzstd1:i386 (!= 1.4.8+dfsg-2.1) but 1.3.8+dfsg-3+deb10u2 is to be installed
 libzstd1:i386 : Breaks: libzstd1 (!= 1.3.8+dfsg-3+deb10u2) but 1.4.8+dfsg-2.1 is to be installed
 zlib1g : Breaks: zlib1g:i386 (!= 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1 is to be installed
 zlib1g:i386 : Breaks: zlib1g (!= 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2 is to be installed
 zlib1g-dev : Depends: zlib1g (= 1:1.2.11.dfsg-1) but 1:1.2.11.dfsg-2 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

apt -f install output:

```
root@CBTS-WBPC5:/home/cbts/Downloads# apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dkms libasound2-dev libblkid-dev libcaca-dev libelf1:i386 libgles1 libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-dev-bin libglvnd-dev libglvnd0:i386
  libmount-dev libomxil-bellagio-bin libomxil-bellagio0 libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libpng-dev libpng-tools
  libpulse-dev libselinux1-dev libsensors5:i386 libsepol1-dev libsfml-audio2.5 libsfml-graphics2.5 libsfml-network2.5
  libsfml-system2.5 libsfml-window2.5 libslang2-dev libtinfo5:i386 libwayland-server0:i386 libxcb-dri2-0:i386 libxcb-dri3-0:i386
  libxcb-glx0:i386 libxcb-present0:i386 libxcb-sync1:i386 libxcb-xfixes0:i386 libxdamage1:i386 libxshmfence1:i386 mono-llvm-tools
  qt5-qmake qt5-qmake-bin qtbase5-dev-tools uuid-dev
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libbsd0 libdrm2:i386 libedit2 libelf1 libexpat1 libncurses6 libstdc++6 libtinfo6 libvulkan1 libwayland-client0 libx11-6
  libx11-xcb1 libxau6 libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-sync1 libzstd1 zlib1g
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdrm2:i386
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libbsd0 libedit2 libelf1 libexpat1 libncurses6 libstdc++6 libtinfo6 libvulkan1 libwayland-client0 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxau6
  libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-present0 libxcb-randr0 libxcb-sync1 libzstd1 zlib1g
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 18 downgraded, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
42 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3,156 kB of archives.
After this operation, 480 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: warning: downgrading libstdc++6:amd64 from 10.2.1-6 to 8.3.0-6
(Reading database ... 313759 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libstdc++6_8.3.0-6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++6:amd64 (8.3.0-6) over (10.2.1-6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6_8.3.0-6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libstdc++6', which is different from other instances of package libstdc++6:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libstdc++6_8.3.0-6_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What I have tried:

- apt -f install
- removed Sid repository and apt update

uname -a: Linux CBTS-WBPC5 4.19.0-16-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.181-1 (2021-03-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, upgrading across major release boundaries like that (oldstable to/from stable to/from unstable, etc) is a ***REALLY BAD IDEA***. Debian has a Backports release tree where it backports updated packages from newer releases which do *NOT* break your current installation--if there is not a backport, it's because it has not (yet) been shown to work without breaking you.

[Read through the whole description below. Understand it. Print it out for a hardcopy for reference later if you hit a point you cannot connect to the internet and view the web. etc.]

You have a lot of work to fix your problem, *if it even is fixable*. You will have to remove any and all repositories that are not designed to work with your installed version. I personally use Buster, and will *NOT* use Stable, even though they are *currently* the same thing. This is because eventually, Sid will become the new Stable, and Buster will become OldStable, and the same chaos you are having now will ensue when you update. (Personally, I think the whole oldstable/stable/unstable thing was and still is one of Debian's most poorly thought out and implemented things!)

Do the following commands o more or less reset your apt cache and database (prefix he commands with `sudo` if you are not performing them while logged in as root):

> apt-get autoremove
> apt-get clean
> apt-get autoclean
> apt-get update
> apt-get check

[Side note: While this process is ongoing, do *not* do any other updates or any other `apt-get update` commands.]

Then, you will have to find every single package that was upgraded to Sid's package level (or does not have a proper Buster version available). You can use [Debian's package search feature](https://packages.debian.org/index) to help narrow down which version are for which releases. Avoid the --force option for now!

Once you have the list of packages you need to downgrade, try to downgrade them all, one by one. Some will fail a this point, so skip them but leave them on the list-and remove the ones that succeed. Once you've gone through the list, go through it again. Do this repeatedly for awhile. This will eventually whittle the list down to a few of the most problematic packages. In some cases, a package may exist in Sid that simply does not exist in Buster--just remove (purge) these packages.

Once you are through the list (possibly a few dozen time), you may still have some packages which simply will not downgrade because their dependencies will not or cannot be downgraded. These are the ones you may have to downgrade with the --force option. Prefer--force  downgrading their dependencies *first*, as once downgraded, the package depending on them may decide it can finally downgrade on it's own.

You will have to go through this process repeatedly a few dozen times. Try to avoid rebooting or restarting services or applications unless you absolutely must. (You do no want to downgrade something that eventually prevents you from booting at all until all it's dependencies are likewise downgraded so it works!)

Eventually, you will downgrade them all or have a smaller number of stubborn packages. At this point, you will have to manually go through them to figure out which seps you need in order to downgrade them. You will have to check their dependencies and such, and possibly remove some packages which should not exist within Buster at all (they are only specific to Sid).

*IF* all goes well, you will hopefully downgrade everything back to a state that is valid within Buster. Once you reach this point, you can safely do an `apt-get update` and upgrade any Buster packages to the latest available (still making certain that you do not update any packages that should belong in Sid but not Buster!)

If all goes well again, you should be done.

If at some point, you reach an un-fixable problem, you may have to go in and manually delete apt's cache(s) of packages, package lists, and so on, to get it to reset to a pristine state. This complication is yet another issue requiring pages of instructions that are to much to post here. There are several Debian specific pages on the web that detail all this, so look them up. (And print them! You want hardcopy access to anything you may need while in the process of downgrading, which may break your internet access in the meantime--so you want paper copies to read and reference. Or if that is too much printing, have a second working computer you can use to access the internet and the web.)

Good luck.